# Why do I get an "Ambiguous dependencies for interface" Exception when I'm already uses the @Produces annotation?

Tags: ejb, java-ee-7

I'm using two Messaging Oriented Middleware in my project. RabbitMQ and Apache Kafka. I have an consumer interface IConsume which are implemented by ConsumerRabbitMQ and ConsumerKafka. At startup going through some conditions I use the @Produces annotation to choose an implementation for the Interface Bean that I will inject, but it gives me this error.

**Exception 1:**

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type IConsume with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.mycompany.chatapp.startup.RunConsumers.ct
  at com.mycompany.chatapp.startup.RunConsumers.ct(RunConsumers.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Session bean [class com.mycompany.chatapp.messagegateway.ConsumerRabbitMQ with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [IConsume],
  - Producer Method [IConsume] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces public com.mycompany.chatapp.startup.MOMConfigBean.produceIConsume()],
  - Session bean [class com.mycompany.chatapp.messagegateway.ConsumerKafka with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are [IConsume]
```

@Default and @Alternative works, but I want it to choose by checking which of the Middleware is running.

The lookup works, I also tried beanName. I think the problem is with the @Produces, but I can't find to seem what.

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MOMConfigBean {
private String mom;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    mom = "Kafka";
}

@EJB(lookup = "java:global/Chatapp/ConsumerKafka!com.mycompany.chatapp.messagegateway.IConsume")
IConsume kafkaConsumer;

@EJB(lookup = "java:global/Chatapp/ConsumerRabbitMQ!com.mycompany.chatapp.messagegateway.IConsume")
IConsume rabbitConsumer;

@Produces
public IConsume produceIConsume() {
    if ("Kafka".equals(mom)) {
        return kafkaConsumer;
    } else {
        return rabbitConsumer;
    }
}


public interface IConsume {
// some code
}

@Stateless
public class ConsumerKafka implements IConsume{
// some code
}

@Stateless
public class ConsumerRabbitMQ implements IConsume {
// some code
}

public class runConsumers{

@Inject
private IConsume ct;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three ambiguous sources of `IConsume` instances:

1. a `ConsumerKafka` EJB
2. a `ConsumerRabbitMQ` EJB
3. an `@Produces public IConsume produceIConsume()` method.

You need to disambiguate the source of the `IConsume` instances using a qualifier.

This qualifier would look something like:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
public @interface ConditionalMom {
}
```

Then qualify the producer:

```
@Produces
@ConditionalMom
public IConsume produceIConsume() {
    if ("Kafka".equals(mom)) {
        return kafkaConsumer;
    } else {
        return rabbitConsumer;
    }
}
```

and the injection site:

```
public class runConsumers{

    @Inject
    @ConditionalMom
    private IConsume ct;

}
```

Now you have a single source of `@ConditionalMom IConsume` instances so it is no longer ambiguous.

You will find that you will be using qualifiers all over the place as you start to further exploit CDI features.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I followed this thread to create the coding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920123/inject-ejb-bean-based-on-conditions/7923159#7923159

Perhaps it was outdated and I assumed because I use the @Produce annotation I didn't have to use a qualifier.

Comment: Yes, that solution does not work as noted in one of the comments